# How do I fix this problem - DERBY SQL Error: SCHEMA DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to run this query, but I get the above SQL error.

```
query = "SELECT Count(*) as itemQuantity FROM ItemTable.Quantity WHERE ItemTable.BarCode = cast("+itemCode+" AS INTEGER)";
```

SQL Error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'ITEMTABLE' does not exist

Comment: are you sure you have a table called `Quantity` inside a schema called `ItemTable`? Are you sure it's not the table that's called `ItemTable`?

Comment: Did you *create* that schema?

Answer (score 0):

It seems "FROM ItemTable.Quantity" is wrong. just change it to "FROM ItemTable"

Answer (score 0):

without using schema

```
query = "SELECT Count(Quantity) as itemQuantity FROM ItemTable WHERE BarCode = cast("+itemCode+" AS INTEGER)";
```

with schema

```
query = "SELECT Count(Quantity) as itemQuantity FROM dbo.ItemTable WHERE BarCode = cast("+itemCode+" AS INTEGER)";
```

in above dbo is database schema you can define your own if you like so

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked, however, I need to count the the number of items stored in each row within the column Quantity. When I run the above code it only returns the number of rows under the column Quantity. Please help.

Comment: instead of count write SUM it will resolve your issue

Comment: query = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) as itemQuantity FROM ItemTable WHERE BarCode = cast("+itemCode+" AS INTEGER)";

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's the ideal person to learn from, straightforward answers, without st..pid and confusing questions. Keep up the good work and thanks again!!!